# git tracks files in directory, but not directory itself - bug in git?

Tags: git, git-submodules

My understanding of git doesn't include this situation. I cannot make 'git status' clean by running `git reset --hard HEAD` and `git clean -fd`. It appears that git is tracking the two files inside a directory, but not the directory itself. Here is an excerpt

```
~/work/ghc/libraries/haskeline ((no branch)) $ git status
# Not currently on any branch.
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   "tests/dummy-I\314\202\302\274I\314\202\302\261I\314\210\302\203/"
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

~/work/ghc/libraries/haskeline ((no branch)) $ git clean -fd
Removing "tests/dummy-I\314\202\302\274I\314\202\302\261I\314\210\302\203/"

~/work/ghc/libraries/haskeline ((no branch)) $ git status
# Not currently on any branch.
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#   deleted:    "tests/dummy-\303\216\302\274\303\216\302\261\303\217\302\203/bar"
#   deleted:    "tests/dummy-\303\216\302\274\303\216\302\261\303\217\302\203/\303\217\302\202\303\216\302\265\303\217\302\201\303\217\302\204"
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

~/work/ghc/libraries/haskeline ((no branch)) $ git reset --hard
HEAD is now at 40bcd6a Fix build on Win64

~/work/ghc/libraries/haskeline ((no branch)) $ git status
# Not currently on any branch.
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   "tests/dummy-I\314\202\302\274I\314\202\302\261I\314\210\302\203/"
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

~/work/ghc/libraries/haskeline ((no branch)) $ git log tests/dummy-Î¼Î±Ï/
~/work/ghc/libraries/haskeline ((no branch)) $ git log tests/dummy-\303\216\302\274\303\216\302\261\303\217\302\203/bar
fatal: ambiguous argument 'testests/dummy-303216302274303216302261303217302203/bar': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

~/work/ghc/libraries/haskeline ((no branch)) $ git log "testests/dummy-\303\216\302\274\303\216\302\261\303\217\302\203/bar"
fatal: ambiguous argument 'testests/dummy-\303\216\302\274\303\216\302\261\303\217\302\203/bar': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

~/work/ghc/libraries/haskeline ((no branch)) $ cd tests/dummy-Î¼Î±Ï/
~/work/ghc/libraries/haskeline/tests/dummy-Î¼Î±Ï ((no branch)) $ ls
Ï?ÎµÏ?Ï?         bar

~/work/ghc/libraries/haskeline/tests/dummy-Î¼Î±Ï ((no branch)) $ git status
# Not currently on any branch.
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   "../dummy-I\314\202\302\274I\314\202\302\261I\314\210\302\203/"
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

~/work/ghc/libraries/haskeline/tests/dummy-Î¼Î±Ï ((no branch)) $ git log bar 
commit e9c39a16fdecf529e7a86beb3971eb351e915de5
Author: Judah Jacobson <judah.jacobson@gmail.com>
Date:   Sun Jul 22 22:14:08 2012 +0000

    Add test folder for unit-testing file completion.

~/work/ghc/libraries/haskeline/tests/dummy-Î¼Î±Ï ((no branch)) $ git log .
commit e9c39a16fdecf529e7a86beb3971eb351e915de5
Author: Judah Jacobson <judah.jacobson@gmail.com>
Date:   Sun Jul 22 22:14:08 2012 +0000

    Add test folder for unit-testing file completion.

~/work/ghc/libraries/haskeline/tests/dummy-Î¼Î±Ï ((no branch)) $ cd ..
~/work/ghc/libraries/haskeline/tests ((no branch)) $ git log dummy-Î¼Î±Ï/
~/work/ghc/libraries/haskeline/tests ((no branch)) $
```

Is this a bug in git that I should report (possibly to do with the non-ascii filenames involved)? If not, could someone explain why this makes sense?

A final note: the libraries/haskeline directory is a git submodule inside the ghc directory. I'm not aware of any way that this should make a difference.
Also, my prompt contains the current git branch. Running the command explicitly gives

```
~/work/ghc/libraries/haskeline/tests ((no branch)) $ git branch
* (no branch)
  master
```

Comment: Do you know that doesn't track directories, only files in directories? That's why you can't track an empty directory using Git, it will just ignore it.

Comment: Git won't removed untracked files during reset.  If you don't want them, delete them.

Comment: @Cupcake @edward I'm aware of these things. My confusion is that I ran `git clean -fd`, and this command removed files that git was tracking - which is clear because running `git reset --hard` restored them (you can see this from the output I included). My understanding has been that `git clean -fd` will not remove any directory that contains a tracked file - is this wrong?